# UITableView not updating labels for Dynamic Type changes

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder, accessibility

I’m using custom `UITableViewCell`s and custom xibs. To support Dynamic Type I’ve implemented `UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification` by listening in `viewDidLoad()`

```
func didChangeContentSizeCategory(notification: NSNotification)
{
    // Dynamic Type preferences were updated. Reload UI.

    myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

My custom xibs make use of font descriptors in Interface Builder:

[image]

Even though this notification is fired (tested with breakpoints) and `myTableView`’s `reloadData()` method is called, it doesn’t update the labels’ contents to make use of the new value.

To my understanding this should work without me doing anything else, is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Automatic support for Dynamic Type in `UITableView` works when using both Auto Layout and self-sizing cells.

So, if you are not doing this, it may be possible that you need to explicitly update your cell's `UILabel` font property wherever your cell is recalculated, as it seems `reloadData()` is not doing this.

For example, before returning your cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` call:

```
cell.headline.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleHeadline)
```

Thus, when a `UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification` is posted, it will explicitly trigger a font update, even when the app is running.

Comment: Do I need to do this even if the `UILabel` is set to a font descriptor using IB?

Comment: Give it a shot-- it would also be helpful if you posted a bit more of your code above to debug.

Comment: It was more the reluctance to double up on code, or at least, design in IB rather than by code